# МерЕжа чи мережА?

Tags: вживання-слів, фонетика

На порталі Мова ДНК Нації знайшла картинку
[image]

Але на телебаченні чую часто "мережА". Це неправильна вимова чи спроба популяризації нового правопису?

Comment: Під новим правописом Ви маєте на увазі проект 2018 року?

Comment: пані Юлія, ви можете приймати відповіді під своїми питаннями, під голосуванням за чи проти питання можна натиснути галочку й дати користувачу, який відповів, додаткову репутацію. Так людина ще більше заохочується до подальших відповідей. Якщо вас влаштовують відповіді під певними питаннями, і ви вважаєте їх повними, будь ласка, не полінуйтесь зробити це.

Answer (score 5):

У [СУМі](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=50596&page=1602) знаходимо мерЕжа. В [Орфографічному словнику](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=162656) мерЕжа. Отже, нормативний наголос мерЕжа. Натрапила на статтю [Як помиляються телеведучі](http://redactor.in.ua/ru/language/7555.Yak_pomilyayutsya_televeduch%D1%96), де також зазначено, що в ЗМІ часто вживають ненормативні наголоси:

> У радіо- й телепередачах, на жаль, дуже часто трапляються відступи від норм української літературної мови. На рівні наголосу чуємо: гра́блі, залоза́, **мережа́,** паралі́ч, Покрова́, су́дно, те́чія, приве́сти, прине́сти, прізвищаКо́валь, Кра́вець. Правильні наголоси - граблі́, за́лоза, **мере́жа**, пара́ліч, Покро́ва, судно́, привести́, принести́, Кова́ль, Краве́ць.

Answer (score 2):

На сайті *"[Словники України](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)" on-line*, в *[Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0)*  та в *Словнику відмінків* вказаний наголос на другий склад.

[image]

Єдиний правильний варіант вимови це ***мере́жа.***